# reception behaviour with multiple listeners on jms queue

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

If there are multiple listeners on a queue with each java process containing a single listener, then what is the pattern of reception when messages arrive on the queue. Will :

1) each listener take turn in receiving messages. ie Message1 goes to Listener1, message 2 goes to listener2 and so on

or

2) it be a random reception

or

3) it be JMS implementation dependent.

I am using Spring DMLC for receiving the messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely indeterminate - it depends on many things...

- the broker
- how long a listener takes to process a message
- prefetch settings
- etc, etc.

It might start off round-robin but will quickly become random (not really random - predictable - the broker will generally send the next message to the first consumer that completes the processing of the previous message).

Comment: Since a message is going to be consumed by only one consumer, what do you mean by the first consumer to complete the processing of previous message

Comment: Let's say you have 4 messages in the queue and 3 consumers. They will each get 1 message; the fourth will go to the consumer that finishes first (unless prefetch is configured in which case it will already have been sent to one of them and queued up locally). You can also have multiple consumers in each container (concurrency); each is treated as a discrete consumer by the broker - it doesn't know anything about the DMLC.